# Struts 2 with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, struts2, thymeleaf

I want to use Thymeleaf as a template engine in my web app. I searched on Google to configure Themeleaf with struts2 and found some solutions with one [plugin](https://github.com/codework/struts2-thymeleaf-plugin). I have configured plugin in my app but I am not able to render page using plugin. instead I am getting error :

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/WEB-INF/templates/hello.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:955)
    com.struts.custom.resulttype.plugin.ThemeleafResult.execute(ThemeleafResult.java:51)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

This is implementation of `DefaultTemplateEngineProvider.java`

```
public class DefaultTemplateEngineProvider implements TemplateEngineProvider {
  // HTML5 is the future!
  private String templateMode = "HTML5";
  private String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
  // This will convert "home" to "/WEB-INF/templates/home.html"
  private String prefix = "/WEB-INF/templates/";
  private String suffix = ".html";
  private boolean cacheable = true;

  // Default template cache TTL to 1 hour. If not set, entries would live in
  // cache until expelled by LRU.
  private Long cacheTtlMillis = 3600000L;

  private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

  /**
   * Configure settings from the struts.xml or struts.properties, using sensible
   * defaults if values are not provided.
   */
  public void configure() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(templateMode);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(characterEncoding);
    templateResolver.setPrefix(prefix);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(suffix);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(cacheable);
    templateResolver.setCacheTTLMs(cacheTtlMillis);

    templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    templateEngine.setMessageResolver(new StrutsMessageResolver());
  }


  public TemplateEngine get() {
    if (templateEngine == null) {
      configure();
    }

    return templateEngine;
  }

  @Inject(value = "struts.thymeleaf.templateMode", required = false)
  public void setTemplateMode(String templateMode) {
    this.templateMode = templateMode;
  }

  @Inject(value = "struts.thymeleaf.encoding", required = false)
  public void setCharacterEncoding(String characterEncoding) {
    this.characterEncoding = characterEncoding;
  }

  @Inject(value = "struts.thymeleaf.prefix", required = false)
  public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
  }

  @Inject(value = "struts.thymeleaf.suffix", required = false)
  public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
    this.suffix = suffix;
  }

  @Inject(value = "struts.thymeleaf.cacheable", required = false)
  public void setCacheable(String cacheable) {
    this.cacheable = Boolean.parseBoolean(cacheable);
  }

  @Inject(value = "struts.thymeleaf.cacheTtlMillis", required = false)
  public void setCacheTtlMillis(String cacheTtlMillis) {
    this.cacheTtlMillis = Long.parseLong(cacheTtlMillis);
  }
}
```

I have written custom result set and configured Thymeleaf as documented on official site. But getting same error.

My Custom result type is

```
public class ThymeleafResult implements Result {
  private String defaultEncoding = "UTF-8";
  private TemplateEngineProvider templateEngineProvider;
  private String templateName;

  /**
   * The result parameter name to set the name of the template to.
   * <p/>
   * IMPORTANT! Struts2 will look for this field reflectively to determine which
   * parameter is the default. This allows us to have a simplified result
   * configuration. Don't remove it!
   */
  public static final String DEFAULT_PARAM = "templateName";

  public ThymeleafResult() {
  }

  public ThymeleafResult(String templateName) {
    this.templateName = templateName;
  }


  public void execute(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = templateEngineProvider.get();

    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    ServletContext servletContext = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();

    Object action = actionInvocation.getAction();

    StrutsContext context = new StrutsContext(request, response, servletContext, action);
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding(defaultEncoding);
    System.out.println(templateName);
    templateEngine.process(templateName, context, response.getWriter());
  }

  @Inject(StrutsConstants.STRUTS_I18N_ENCODING)
  public void setDefaultEncoding(String defaultEncoding) {
    this.defaultEncoding = defaultEncoding;
  }

  @Inject
  public void setTemplateEngineProvider(TemplateEngineProvider templateEngineProvider) {
    this.templateEngineProvider = templateEngineProvider;
  }

  public void setTemplateName(String templateName) {
    this.templateName = templateName;
  }
```

And struts.xml is

```xml
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000000" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
     <bean type="org.codework.struts.plugins.thymeleaf.spi.TemplateEngineProvider" name="default" class="org.codework.struts.plugins.thymeleaf.spi.DefaultTemplateEngineProvider" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="thymeleaf" class="org.codework.struts.plugins.thymeleaf.ThymeleafResult"/>
        </result-types>
        <default-action-ref name="home"></default-action-ref>
        <action name="home" class="com.demo.example.Welcome">
             <result name="success" type="thymeleaf">/WEB-INF/templates/hello.html</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Could you show us your code and how you have it configured to run, instead of just the error? (More because I'm too lazy to read the documentation than anything else)

Comment: Check the location of template files, Struts put their templates under resources.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja i have added more details. Please check what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution: I was doing a wrong mapping in struts.xml.

I just replaced

```xml
<result name="success" type="thymeleaf">/WEB-INF/templates/hello.html</result>
```

with

```xml
<result name="success" type="thymeleaf">hello</result>
```

and it worked.